# changing table td color based on a variable value

Tags: php, html, css

i am trying to change the color of a td element in a table based on the statusID. status can be either zero or one. I wanna show the td as red if it its status is zero and green if status is one. my code doesn't work. I am getting the status of the device to a variable calle $statusDevice. any suggestions are welcomed.

```
$colors = [ '#FF0000',' #008000'];

$conn= mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db ) or die("Could not connect: " .mysqli_error($conn) );
$sql = "SELECT Name FROM parameter WHERE Device='A'";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    echo '<table>';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

      $bgColor= $colors[$statusDevice];
      echo $bgColor;
      //echo $colors[0];

      echo '<tr><th>Status of Device</th>';

      echo '<td bgcolor= $bgColor); >' . $row['A']. '</td></tr>';

      echo $bgColor;

    }echo "</table>";
  }
```

Comment: What isn't working ?

Comment: <div style="background-color:<?=(($status%0)?'red':'yellow');?>;">blah</div>

Comment: Also do not put variables in single ticks. Check your source code. You'll figure out they are not being evaluated to their value that way.

Comment: Where's `$statusDevice` declared?

Comment: `bgcolor` is deprecated. Instead use `style` as @ChrisS. suggested

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes `"` not single `'` quotes to interprete variables in strings.

change this line

```
  echo '<td bgcolor= $bgColor); >' . $row['A']. '</td></tr>';
```

to this:

```
  echo "<td bgcolor= $bgColor; >" . $row['A']. '</td></tr>';
```

*And I think you have an extra parenthesis in your code (I fixed it)*

Besides `bgcolor` is deprecated you should use `style` instead like So:

```
  echo "<td style='background-color: $bgColor;'>" . $row['A']. '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: _Small Note_ See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359705/changing-table-td-color-based-on-a-variable-value#comment97443292_55359705)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatinate varibles with string:

```
echo '<td bgcolor= '.$bgColor.'>' . $row['A']. '</td></tr>';
```

Or use " instead of '

Comment: not sure which is more oooooldschool, using td or using the deprecated attribute bgcolor

Comment: Here is question answer, not programmin school :) I code like this at start - it normal IMHO. He will study for normal coding in process.

Comment: Not offending. Just pointing out you're using things that are likely to be removed from browsers and stop working anytime soon, if not already removed (bgcolor). Don't get me wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, `bgcolor` is deprecated so just use this

```
echo '<td style= "background-color:'.$bgColor.';" >' . $row['A']. '</td></tr>'
```

instead of